# Custom Chat Box Control - How to make it scrollable plus more

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I am making a simple chat box control. Its just a hobby project to learn. I want to make my own control like below :

[image]

I have learnt how to paint graphics and text onto a custom control surface inheriting from `control` using OnPaint. But problem is I want this control to have the elements in the screenshot, most importantly to be able to infinitly scroll. Had a try googling but didnt find any answer.

Also because its painted, I probably wont be able to differentiate between the different users, or the speech bubbles as they are all the same to the control.

But is there a way to know the user is `clicking` on a certain bubble, or certain user? And the other question was how to make it `scrollable`?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it scrollable, you should try to make each comment a separate panel & add that panel to your control.
Then set the autosize property of your control to true (you will need to make your control a panel, inheriting control doesn't have autosize property).

For the clicking on the bubbles, I suggest again to make each bubble a custom control & then add it to the panel (the panel inside your main panel), then just use the MouseEnter event.